# DNS Nameserver Lookup - Meteor JS

Tags: node.js, meteor, dns

I have a nameserver url eg. ns1.example.com, and I need to find the server's IP address.

I'm sure this can be done, it is a simple task, but I fail to find a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```js
var dns = Npm.require('dns');
var lookup = Meteor.wrapAsync(dns.lookup);
try {
  var ip = lookup('example.com');
  console.log(ip);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('not found');
}
```

Comment: It returns an `Unexpected identifier` error at the "Npm.require". Should I use [npm require](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm)?

Comment: It must be run on the server - npm isn't available on the client. If you need the result on the client, you will need to use a meteor method. I can rewrite the answer to demonstrate this if needed.

Comment: I ran it in the server method, error was caused by something else entirely. Btw I thought I need that meteorhacks npm package to load npm packages. It works thanks!

Comment: You need `meteorhacks:npm` or a custom package only for npm pacakges which are __not__ part of the core node API. `dns` is in node core so you can just use `Npm.require`.